# I cannot enable macro in my Excel, there is always a pop-up of Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications that says 'missing end bracket'

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I found this problem when I want to open an Excel document sent by my co-worker, the file has a macro in it but I can't find a way to enable it.

When I click to enable macros this always happens and after one attempt of enabling macro, now everytime I open a file with a macro in it this always happens.

[image]

Comment: Your macro code looks corrupted/invalid syntax?

Comment: It appears the code was written in a different language and is decoding incorrectly based on your regional settings. `[` leads the complie error. For example, `Dim 变量 as String 变量 = 1` is valid in Chinese Windows. but it may causes compile errors in English systems.